# ListBox.SelectedItems for multiple variables

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I'm trying to assign multiple licenses to an exchange user with a listbox to have the options to pick 1-3. How can I seperate the outcome into multiple variables to assign them correctly or can I pass them through as one? I shortened the code and cut out the form.

```
#Abfrage ob eine oder mehrere freie Lizenzen zugewiesen werden sollen

$listBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Listbox
$listBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40)
$listBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20)

$listBox.SelectionMode = 'MultiExtended'

[void] $listBox.Items.Add('ATP_Enterprise')
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('O365_Business_Essentials')
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('O365_Business_Premium')

$listBox.Height = 70
$form.Controls.Add($listBox)
$form.Topmost = $true

$result = $form.ShowDialog()

if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
{
    $planName = $listBox.SelectedItems
    $planName -join ','
}

#Zuweisung einer Lizenz zum User

$userUPN="$EMail"
$License = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.AssignedLicense
$License.SkuId = (Get-AzureADSubscribedSku | Where-Object -Property SkuPartNumber -Value $planName -EQ).SkuID
$LicensesToAssign = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.AssignedLicenses
$LicensesToAssign.AddLicenses = $License
Set-AzureADUserLicense -ObjectId $userUPN -AssignedLicenses $LicensesToAssign
```

Comment: Look at `$ListBox.SelectedItems.Text`

Comment: That doesnt work at all. I placed it instead of `$ListBox.SelectedItems`

Comment: It;s not that that;s wrong.....

Comment: Again please? I don't understand your response...

Answer (score 0):

This seems incorrect to me...

```
$License.SkuId = (Get-AzureADSubscribedSku | Where-Object -Property SkuPartNumber -Value $planName -EQ).SkuID
```

Surely should be:

```
$License.SkuId = (Get-AzureADSubscribedSku | Where-Object { $_.SkuPartNumber -EQ $planName.Text} ).SkuID
```

Comment: i got mine from microsoft. :D